# Creation of folder in windows using chef

Tags: ruby, resources, chef-infra, recipe

Code:

```
directory node['soft_packname']['source_path'] do
  action :create
  recursive true
end
```

Attribute :

```
default['soft_packname']['source_path'] = 'C:\nscpsource'
```

But I am an error when I run chef-client on this resource/recipe.

```
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 08 seconds
[2018-04-06T18:10:54+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/opscode/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2018-04-06T18:10:54+05:30] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2018-04-06T18:10:54+05:30] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I am unable to create the folder using directory resource in windows ..I am passing attribute. Folder is not created...thanks for your quick response

Comment: `undefined method []' for nil:NilClass` could probably mean or `default` or  `default['soft_packname']` are nil values, check them first setting the value of `['source_path']`.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian but could you please share me an example how to set these attribute values

Comment: Try printing chef log output like inside recipe and see what it is giving you
Chef::Log.info("attribute #{node['soft_packname']}")